# React Native : Searching, Filter, and Base View all in one route

Tags: search, reactjs, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, react-native

I would like to ask, is there any solution to come out with something like Messenger(Mobile App) searching function? The route is having a basic view elements. When user is typing in some words, the search will start to function, within the same screen, another view overlap to show the filter list. I had tried to use react-native-overlap module but it not work well.

```
var React = require ('react-native');
var {
  Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Dimensions, Image, Platform, ScrollView, ReactNative, DeviceEventEmitter,TouchableOpacity
} = React;
var NavigationBar = require ('../Components/NavigationBar');
var SearchBarFromNodeModule = require ('react-native-search-bar');
var Overlay=require('react-native-overlay');

var Recent = React.createClass({

getInitialState(){
  return {
    isVisible:'aa',
  };
},

onNameChanged(e){
  //todo something here
//  alert('asd');
},

render (){
return (
  <View>
  <View style={styles.navbarContainer}>
  <SearchBarFromNodeModule ref='searchBar' placeholder='Search' showsCancelButton={true} onChange={this.onNameChanged} />
  </View>
  <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column'}}>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#F4FA58',flex:1,height:40}}/>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#58FAF4',flex:1,height:40}}/>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#F4FA58',flex:1,height:40}}/>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#58FAF4',flex:1,height:40}}/>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#F4FA58',flex:1,height:40}}/>
  <View style={{backgroundColor:'#58FAF4',flex:1,height:40}}/>
  </View>
  </View>
    );
},
});

var styles=StyleSheet.create({
  navbarContainer: {
    height: 65,
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  button:{
    height:40,
    textAlign:'center',
    fontSize:18,
    marginBottom:10,
    marginTop:10,
    color:'blue',
  }`enter code here`
});

module.exports = Recent;
```

Now there is some color boxes after the search bar, when user is typing something, onChange function will take place. But I have no idea how to overlap the color boxes.

Comment: This sounds pretty straight forward to implement. Can you show what you have tried so that we can help you find the issue with the way you tried to implement it?

Comment: Hi, @rmevans9, I had made some changes. Can you try to help me out?

Comment: I had tried something on the code by setting the height for the View. When onChange event occurring, the height of the view set to 0, the View I want it to be visible, I changed the height to certain value. But it sound something like hard code. Or it is actually code like that?

Answer (score 0):

This gets the job mostly done. The only issue is the search results box renders under the text view below the search input. This could be corrected in a few ways but I personally would likely look to the zIndex feature introduced in 0.30 that is coming out soon.

https://rnplay.org/apps/CJNPWg

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';

class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.search.toUpperCase() !== 'BAM') {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.searchResults}>
        <Text>
          Do whatever your heart desires here...    Might I recomend a list view??
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput 
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}} 
          value={this.props.search} 
          onChangeText={this.props.onChange} 
          placeholder="Try 'BAM'!" 
        />
        <SearchResults search={props.search} /> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentSearch: ''
  };

  onCurrentSearchChange(text) {
    this.setState({
      currentSearch: text
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>Enter your search</Text>
       <SearchBox search={this.state.currentSearch} onChange={this.onCurrentSearchChange.bind(this)} />
       <Text>Some text below the search box...</Text>
     </View>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 30
  },
  searchResults: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @rmevans9 . Base on your answer, the SearchResults' component will not overlap/cover those elements under SearchBox, but it only push down the elements. I am looking forward for the z-index function as well!

Comment: It does overlay them, it just looks odd because of the ordering of the elements on the page. 0.30 got released yesterday so you can give the zindex route a shot now.

Comment: sorry... Just realized it does overlay! Thanks again! I will read through the react-native 0.30 z-index doc and try to code it out.